# Extracting probability distributions from data

Tags: probability, data-transformation, dataset

I have two discrete random variables $X,\,T\in \{1,2,\dots,n\}$ and lots of measurements. Each measurement $M_i$ gives me one value of $T$ and probability distribution for $X$, for example:

[image]

I'd like to get from this data the following:

- $P(X=x_k \cap T=t_i)$
- $P(X=x_k)$
- $P(T=t_i)$
- $P(X=x_k |\, T=t_i)$

How do I do this? Can I write $P(X=x_k)=\sum_j P(X=x_k|M_j)P(M_j)$ with the assumption that $P(M_j)$ are all equal?

Code to create the example in Python pandas:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "X": [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
    "T": [5, 5, 7, 7, 3, 3],
    "M": [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3],
    "P(X | M)": [0.5, 0.5, 0.1, 0.9, 0.7, 0.3]})
```